# PHP Regex - Exclude 3 conditions and return the rest

Tags: php, regex

What I have now:

1. `preg_match('/title:(.+?)(?=\s|$)/',$str, $result);` // Gives me words starts with title: and end with space.
2. `preg_match('/body:(.+?)(?=\s|$)/',$str, $result);` // Gives me words starts with body: and end with space.
3. `preg_match_all('/#([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+)/u', $str, $result);` // Gives me array of words starts with # and put them into an array.

How to exclude the above and get the rest that doesn't match in one expression?

I want to take the user input, and:

1. Remove string (I expect just one) that starts with `title:` and ends with a space.
2. Remove string (I expect just one) that starts with `body:` and ends with a space.
3. Remove strings (I expect multiple) that starts with `#` and ends with a space.
4. Get whatever words are left.

Ex: `title:hello mexico body:something #css#php #html city`

Result should be: `mexico city`

Comment: Not sure if this works for your real input but if you would `preg_replace` the alternated patterns to empty string `mexico city` would be left (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMCitd/2), I slightly modified the pattern).

Comment: @bobblebubble I can see this working on the site, but not on my code, `preg_match('/\b(?:title|body):.+?(?:\s|$)|#[\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+\s?/',$str, $result);` and the output of `dd($result);` is `array:1 [0 => "title:hello "]`.

Comment: As mentioned you would do this using `preg_replace`, see [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##Pc1BC4IwGMbxu5/ixQlTlD7ALHbtUOG9RdQabjDdcAuS1K@@nIcuf3jew@@10oawp82xSZLM@QEOgL3yWhAptDbQiY/iBp7mNRJnOuGl6ltA3DlkpQUkfaeBKz/i@g/YQbT3QVj94CLHC3vmlGzmFJmC7Eq6XpibsmJCV2a/DZ/XXmJOMed@vpXM0eWNK0jTCiJcrA8El2YbdQg/).

Comment: I missed that, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Do you have a sample string that is not satisfied by `preg_replace('/(?:\btitle:|\bbody:|#)\w+\s?/', '', $str)`?  If so, it would be a good idea to add another sample string to your question body that expresses the potential variability of your input text.  Why are you doing this task?  Would you rather generate an array of non-prefixed words? `['mexico', 'city']`?  https://3v4l.org/l7CG4

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm building a search input and wanted to give users a way to filter their search right in the input field. Not sure if I'm gonna need the result to be in array so thanks for that example as well :)

Comment: Well, we need your question to be resolved by an answer (if not closed/deleted).  If you want what bob is offering, then ask them to post an answer.  If you want something else, please clarify your question body with the expected result.  If you want something that I've suggested, please let me know and I'll post an answer.  All questions that exist on SO should recieve some sort of system-recognized resolution.

Comment: Bob's answer is my solution, I don't know how to select that, can I just delete the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\b(?:title|body):\S+|#\w+)\s?~u', "", $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OVnMrW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKilYs/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\b(?:title|body):\S+|#\w+)` - either of

  - `\b(?:title|body):\S+` - a word boundary (`\b`), then `title` or `body`, then `:` and then one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `|` - or
  - `#\w+`  - a `#` char and then one or more Unicode (due to `u` flag) word chars
- `\s?`  - an optional whitespace (change `?` to `*` if you need to match zero or more whitespaces).